# Twilio callback is not working in my .NET service

Tags: asp.net, .net, servicestack, twilio, twilio-api

I am developing an SMS service which is expected to send SMS. Apart from that, I need to track status of the SMS.

I am using Twilio as an SMS provider, and ServiceStack to implement Service Layer.

I can see the SMS being sent successfully, however, I am not getting any response on the configured callback URL.

```
var message = MessageResource.Create(to: new PhoneNumber(sms.ToNumber),
from: new PhoneNumber(sms.FromNumber),
body: sms.MessageBody,
statusCallback: new Uri("http://8754622.ngrok.io/json/oneway/TwilioCallBack"));
```

I have downloaded Ngrok, and running it to map the localhost site to make it accessible externally.

Following is how I am trying to handle the callback from Twilio

```
public object Post(TwilioCallBack request)
{
    return _notificationProviderManager.SaveCallBackEvent(request.MessageStatus);
}

[Route("/TwilioCallBack", "POST")]
public class TwilioCallBack : INotificationCallBack
{
    public int id { get; set; }
        public string MessageStatus { get; set; }
}
```

While I can see the SMS getting delivered to the destination number, I cannot see anything happening at call back level.

Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing the callback in the ngrok logs (check http://127.0.0.1:4040 while ngrok is running) or not at all?

Comment: I just checked the log, and I am not seeing the callback in the ngrok logs.

Comment: I have also verified that I can receive the response from Twilio, if I use requestbin URL, but I want to use ngrok as I want to perform further actions based on response. Also, If I simply copy-paste the Ngrok POST url in PostMan application, I can see the service getting invoked and code getting executed. Not sure, why Twilio is unable to send response to Ngrok configured URL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot many attempts, and referring various posts, I came to know that Twilio callbacks are not working properly if the request contains a query string.

In those cases, Twilio reports `Failed to parse StatusCallback URL per RFC2396` error which we can see in Twilio's debugger.

This post briefly addresses the issue - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/145 The issue is marked as resolved in Github by someone, but I was still facing the same issue. Hoping for someone to look into there.

Unfortunately, I had to remove query string parameters from the callback URL, afterwhich I could see the POST requests coming in and hitting the service.

Comment: Callbacks should work with a query string. Can you share the URL that caused the `Failed to parse` error?

Answer (score 2):

In case the callback is a GET, I'd leave the Route and impl open to accept **any** HTTP Verb, e.g:

```
public object Any(TwilioCallBack request) { ... }

[Route("/TwilioCallBack")]
public class TwilioCallBack { ... }
```

Since you've defined a custom route, you should likely be using it (i.e. instead of the predefined route) in the callback:

```
statusCallback: new Uri("http://8754622.ngrok.io/TwilioCallBack"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, and much appreciated. As per the twilio official document, callback is POST.

Comment: I could confirm that the response we get from Twilio is POST, as I checked it inside "requestbin".